# See total amount of views in project android

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know if there is a way to see all the views, LinearLayout, TextView etc in a project on android studio?

I am using the Hierarchy Viewer in the android device monitor to prune some unnecessary views using the xml merge tag and I what to show that the views are actually being removed by doing a before and after count. So far im counting them all manually from the tree view and its painfully slow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way:

```
LinearLayout llParent = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llParent);;

int childViewCount = llParent.getChildCount();
```

Hope it will help you.